# Why am I seeing elapsed game time differ from total game time in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I was trying three different ways of using `ElapsedGameTime` and `TotalGameTime`, because I want an exact match, so everything is updated/drawn accordingly.

As I was experimenting, I learned that the very first update, `ElapsedGameTime` and `TotalGameTime` are both 0.

Second update, `ElapsedGameTime` is 0.0166667, which is correct (60 updates per second). But `TotalGameTime` is 0, I don't understand why.

So, if I start to add from the **third** update (`time += gameTime.ElapsedTime`), `ElapsedGameTime` is equal to `TotalGameTime`, otherwise there will be always a 0.0166667 difference.

Can someone explain that to me?

**UPDATED: code**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestTime
{
    class TimeTest2
    {
        TimeSpan totalTimeElapsed;
        TimeSpan frequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5f);

        int times = 0;
        int timesCheckpoint = 1;

        public void load()
        {

        }

        public void initialize()
        {   
            totalTimeElapsed = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        public void update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            times++;
            String debug = "";
            TimeSpan zero = TimeSpan.Zero;

            if( times > 2 )
            {
                totalTimeElapsed += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;  
            }

            if( totalTimeElapsed != gameTime.TotalGameTime )
            {
                debug += " Diff time:"+times+" ["+totalTimeElapsed.ToString() + " != " + gameTime.TotalGameTime.ToString() + "]";
            }

            TimeSpan checkpoint = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5f*timesCheckpoint);
            if( gameTime.TotalGameTime >= checkpoint )
            {
                debug += "5.5f MARK ";
                timesCheckpoint++;
            }

            if( !debug.Equals("") )
            {
                addDebug(debug + "  -" + gameTime.TotalGameTime.ToString());
                addDebug("");
            }
        }

        public void draw()
        {

        }

        public void addDebug(string str)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting discovery.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you are reading these values `GameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds`, or `GameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds`?

Comment: I went ahead and pinged Shawn Hargreaves. Maybe he can answer this :)

Comment: I use TimeSpan.toString()

Comment: can you post the code you are using to determine this?

Comment: I posted my code. If you change `if( times > 2 )` to any other number, you will see in output window the difference.
I hope I didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you are skipping the first two frames so they can never be the same

Comment: If you run it, they are the same. If you start adding from frame 0 (or just leave `totalTimeElapsed += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;` every frame), they will be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a little bug, or a precisely correct behaviour, from which point you want to look at it. See, the `Update` method is called **twice** before first call to `Draw`, first time being outside of a main game loop.

`TotalGameTime` is updated in the moment between end of the `Update` and beginning of the `Draw`, *inside the game loop*. `ElapsedGameTime` on the other hand is updated after start of the main loop and before `Update`. Both of them are initialized to `0` before call to the first `Update`.

If you [read the description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime_members%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) of a `ElapsedGameTime` is says:

> The amount of elapsed game time **since the last update**.

At the first frame *inside the game loop* it is a *second* `Update` call. So `ElapsedGameTime` shows time elapsed since first `Update` call.

OTOH, `TotalGameTime` says:

> The amount of game time **since the start of the game**.

This is a more vague, but it looks like game can't be considered started, until it entered a main loop and begins drawing itself. Thus `TotalGameTime` updates itself first time after *second* call to `Update`. Hence the difference you observe.